# How can I send AJAX request on URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am not sure if you guys will undestand me because I am spanish and I speak little english but I'll try it:
I would like when user sends in URL browser like http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=000000001 the browser don't send a request to the server,and AJAX loads the content inside of a DIV.
How can I make it work?
I hope you can help me and undertand me.
Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do that. When user types `http://www.facebook.com` he will arrive to facebook website, not to your website.

Comment: its just an example, but http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=000000001 does no ajax magic at all - but check http://www.facebook.com/#!/profile.php?id=000000001 (no ajax thou, but a JS based redirect)

Answer (score 1):

The browser will always reload the page if you change the address. The Ajax way of handling page changes is to work with the hash tag, which is everything after the pound sign ( # )

www.example.com#page=one
www.example.com#page=two
www.example.com#page=three&more=params

Answer (score 1):

Thats a complex issue, you can ether use hashbangs ( http://www.facebook.com/profile.php#!000000001) because they don't force the browser to (re)load a page, but you can catch them via AJAX if the page is loaded. If you don't want to use hashbangs the HTML5 History Interface http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html would be a Way to go, but its not supported by many browsers, but i made some working stuff under chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fiddler to sniff the data sent to the server through AJAX, Then you can write HTTPWebRequest/Response to simulate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GET on url with this function to make an Ajax call :

```
$.extend({
    getUrlVars: function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    },
    getUrlVar: function(name){
        return $.getUrlVars()[name];
    }
});
```

And parse arguments :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // load ajax call
    if( $.getUrlVar('param') != null ){
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                something_var: $.getUrlVar('param')
            },
            success: function(data){
              alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Example url : http://www.website.com/?param=ok

Hope it's what you want :)